# How i turn smartphone screen horizontal when he was open my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How I turn the smartphone screen horizontal when he was opening my site?

Comment: `body { transform: rotate(-90deg) }` ;p on a serious note, probably not possible as generally devices handle screen rotation

Answer (score 1):

I found an article on this topic before some days ago and here it is: [How to Change Screen Orientation with Javascript](https://usefulangle.com/post/105/javascript-change-screen-orientation) In here, you can see a live [demo](https://usefulangle.com/demos/105/screen.html) of that. I have just copied and pasted them in the code snippet as well but I think it won't run properly in here because it is inside a snippet.

```js
var _LOCK_BUTTON = document.querySelector("#lock-landscape-button"),
    _UNLOCK_BUTTON = document.querySelector("#unlock-button"),
    _STATUS = document.querySelector("#orientation-status");

_STATUS.innerHTML = screen.orientation.type + ' mode';

// upon lock to landscape-primary mode
document.querySelector("#lock-landscape-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(document.documentElement.requestFullscreen)
        document.querySelector("#container").requestFullscreen();
    else if(document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen)
        document.querySelector("#container").webkitRequestFullScreen();

    screen.orientation.lock("landscape-primary")
        .then(function() {
            _LOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'none';
            _UNLOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'block';
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });
});

// upon unlock
document.querySelector("#unlock-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    screen.orientation.unlock();

    _LOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'block';
    _UNLOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'none';
});

// when screen orientation changes
screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", function() {
    _STATUS.innerHTML = screen.orientation.type + ' mode';
});

// on exiting full-screen lock is automatically released
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function() {
    _LOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'block';
    _UNLOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'none';
});

document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function() {
    _LOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'block';
    _UNLOCK_BUTTON.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #336699;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    
}

#container:fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#container:-webkit-full-screen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#orientation-status {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0;
    color: white;
}

button {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #336699;
    color: #336699;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
}

#lock-landscape-button {
    
}

#unlock-button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p id="orientation-status"></p>
    <div id="buttons-container">
        <button id="lock-landscape-button">Lock to Landscape Mode</button>
        <button id="unlock-button">Unlock</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Before going to landscape mode, screen should be in fullscreen mode. Otherwise it won't work because of some security issues.

Except this method, you can also rotate the whole body by adding this `body { transform: rotate(-90deg) }` CSS code but I can't be sure about that because most of the time, it will not work properly as how as you need.

Thanks and best regards!